# APCIterator empty

Tags: php, apc

I have enabled APC in `php.ini`, and looking at `phpinfo()`, it all seems ok.
I also have `apc.enable_cli=1` directive in `php.ini`.
I've stored several keys that start with `raw_` prefix and they get stored (`apc_store()` returns `true`, `apc_fetch()` returns the value for that key.

All ok so far.

So I wanted to use `APCIterator` to fetch all keys that start with `raw_`, using this statement:

`$iterator = new APCIterator("user", '/^raw_\.*/');`

A key looks like this:

`raw_2014-04-17 12:19:00_0.68206200 1397726355534f9c93a68649.18047787158329`

It seems that if I `print_r($iterator)` or iterate it using `foreach()`, it is empty.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was this: [How can I get PHP to use the same APC cache when invoked on the CLI and the web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439262/how-can-i-get-php-to-use-the-same-apc-cache-when-invoked-on-the-cli-and-the-web)

I used CLI mode to fetch from APC and used store() via HTTP request. APC does not share data between Apache and CLI